# ¿como hacer una lista de opciones de años de forma dinamica?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Buenas:
La duda que me surge es como puedo cargar las opciones de un formulario de forma dinamica.

Tengo este formulario:

```
MESES_CHOICE = (
('','Selecciona'),
('01','Enero'),
('02','Febrero'),
('03','Marzo'),
('04','Abril'),
('05','Mayo'),
('06','Junio'),
('07','Julio'),
('08','Agosto'),
('09','Septiembre'),
('10','Octubre'),
('11','Noviembre'),
('12','Diciembre'),)

AÑO_CHOICE = (
('','Selecciona'),
('2018','2018'),
('2017','2017'),)


class FechaForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['mes'].required = False
    self.fields['año'].required = False

mes = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MESES_CHOICE)
año = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AÑO_CHOICE)
```

necesito sustituir el choice de año por una lista dinamica que se genere desde el año actual hasta el 2017 para no tener que modificarla a mano cada año

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes calcularlo usando por ejemplo el modulo time y creando una funcion para que calcule desde un año inicial al año actual. En el caso que te pongo es desde 2010

```
import time
def yearChoice():
    a = time.strftime("%Y")
    resultado=[]
    resultado.append(('','Selecciona'))
    for i in range(2010,int(a)+1):
        resultado.append((str(i),str(i)))
    return tuple(resultado)
```

Y cambiar la linea donde defines el año por

```
año = forms.ChoiceField(choices=yearChoice())
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabia que podia pasar una funcion como valor

Comment: @FDelgado no esta pasando la funcion, es esta pasando la tupla que retorna la funcion.

Comment: Ojo que eso va a fallar cuando el año cambie. Esa función va a ejecutarse cuando arranques el servidor. Por ejemplo, si arrancas tu aplicación el 31 de diciembre de 2018, el 01 de enero de 2019 no vas a ver el 2019 como opción, salvo que reinicies la aplicación. En el caso del año no es muy grave, pero si fuera meses por ejemplo, sería mucho peor.
Lo ideal es que calcules el valor de choices cada vez que se cree una instancia del formulario. Para eso deberías hacerlo en el método `__init__`

Comment: Desconocemos los detalles del proyecto, pero yo lo incluria la funcion en el models.py definiendo el campo mas o menos asi: `año = models.CharField(max_length = 4, choices=yearChoice())` para que cada vez que django use ese campo en cualquier formulario se ejecute de nuevo la función.